# What is the key difference between Subject<T> and ReplaySubject<T>?

Tags: c#, system.reactive

What is the difference between `System.Reactive.Subjects.Subject<T>` and `System.Reactive.Subjects.ReplaySubject<T>` classes?

One doesn't derive from another, but they have the same description and implement same interfaces in MSDN.

Comment: Read the bottom paragraph of https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh242970(v=vs.103).aspx

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Take this code:

```
var subject = new Subject<int>();

subject.OnNext(42);
subject.OnCompleted();

subject.Subscribe(x => Console.WriteLine(x));
```

And compare to this:

```
var subject = new ReplaySubject<int>();

subject.OnNext(42);
subject.OnCompleted();

subject.Subscribe(x => Console.WriteLine(x));
```

The first produces no values. The second produces `42`.

Basically `Subject` only produces values to current subscribers and `ReplaySubject` remembers values for future subscribes (when it "replays" the values).